# NSUserTrackingUsageDescription required - Appstore [When upload app to store]

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, app-store-connect

Before submitting my application to  App Store, I added NSUserTrackingUsageDescription to info.plist, however the following issue persists. I've tried twice to publish my application, but nothing has worked. This is an app store error :

> Unable to Submit for Review

> The items below are required to start the review process:
> Your app contains NSUserTrackingUsageDescription, indicating that it may request permission to track users. To submit for review, update your App Privacy response to indicate that data collected from this app will be used for tracking purposes, or update your app binary and upload a new build

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update about user data tracking in the App Privacy section of App Store Connect.

PS : You only need to use the NSUserTrackingUsageDescription property in the info.plist if you are collecting user data for Advertising and/or Third-Party libraries.

If you keep the information within your app, or for authentication purposes, you are not Tracking; therefore, you do not need this property.

Comment: but I already add this property to plist but still it throw this error

Comment: Hey, you need to update about user data tracking in the App Privacy section of App Store Connect.

Comment: but what is the 3rd party? Firebase or Appcenter Analytics are counted? because this data is only available for us, not for 3rd party.

Comment: @Emil anything apart from your own server (for your own use) is considered as 3rd party. So yes Firebase services and others are 3rd party services.

Answer (score 0):

Please add location permission in your app privacy

I attach screen shot for reference:

[image]

U can see this type of box after adding permission

[image]